# ROS noetic and Python 3.9

Tags: python, ros-noetic

I have ROS noetic installed on Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.8. I would like to upgrade my Python to 3.9 and make it the default version. Will it have any effect on my ROS installation ?

Comment: No it will not have any effects, since 3.9 is backwards compatible with 3.8. This is also a similar question to [this one](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/105502/running-ros-built-from-source-with-specific-python-version). Also if you want a clear answer on how to do it [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/340341/how-do-i-specify-the-version-of-python3-for-ros2/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the python version in the environment you should build your workspace from source with the new python version as we use python bindings in many places in the codebase. There are things in the system that will continue to work due to the compatibility but depending on what features you use your mileage will vary, and you may get explainable crashes on things where python bindings are used.

To be very specific don't use debian packages of ROS with a different version of python on your system.

Answer (score -1):

`pip install pyyaml==5.3.1 rospkg==1.5.0`

make sure using this package version ,or the node will not work. i don't why ,but this is my solution .and now i change it to python3.9 finally.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Julian. Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. Very short answers cannot do this, so please edit your answer to explain why it is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed. See [answer] for more info.

Comment: Additionally, your answer doesn't appear to address the question: "Will [upgrading Python] have any effecto on my ROS installation?" Why do you give those versions of those components? What errors were you seeing before that led you to believe there was some issue with those components?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/21751)